# Organizar um json e escrever os resultados

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte json:

```
{  
"result":[  
  {  
     “COD”:[10,3,4,11,1],
     "DESCRICAO”:[mouse,teclado,monitor,webcam,celular],
     "ESTOQUE”:[10,2,5,1,0],
     "QUANT_UNID":[ UN,UN,UN,UN,CX]
  }
]
}
```

Em cada campo do json eu tenho um `array`, como faço para escrever os produtos em ordem?

exemplo:

```
10 mouse 10 UN
3 teclado 2 un
4 monitor 5 un
11 webcam 1 un
1 celular 0 cx
```

Comment: Associar a chave ao valor?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, quero colocar em uma lista os produtos. Porem os códigos, descrição, estoque e unidade. estão em array separados.

Comment: Mas o json está mal formatado, ajadaria se colocasses bem, para poder testar mais facilement

Comment: Só pra constar, este JSON é invalido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Só pra constar**, este JSON está em formato inválido:

```
{  
"result":[  
  {  
     “COD”:[10,3,4,11,1],
     "DESCRICAO”:[mouse,teclado,monitor,webcam,celular],
     "ESTOQUE”:[10,2,5,1,0],
     "QUANT_UNID":[ UN,UN,UN,UN,CX]
  }
]
}
```

Corrija primeiro ele, deve ficar assim:

```
{  
"result":[  
  {  
     "COD":[10,3,4,11,1],
     "DESCRICAO":["mouse", "teclado", "monitor", "webcam", "celular" ],
     "ESTOQUE":[10,2,5,1,0],
     "QUANT_UNID":[ "UN", "UN", "UN", "UN", "CX" ]
  }
]
}
```

Depois de corrigido (suponho que ele seja dinâmico) basta usar um `for` se todos itens tiverem a mesma quantidade:

```php
<?php

$json = '    {
    "result":[
      {
         "COD":[10,3,4,11,1],
         "DESCRICAO":["mouse", "teclado", "monitor", "webcam", "celular" ],
         "ESTOQUE":[10,2,5,1,0],
         "QUANT_UNID":[ "UN", "UN", "UN", "UN", "CX" ]
      }
    ]
    }';

$parsed = json_decode($json);

$results = $parsed->result;

foreach ($results as $item) {
    $cod = $item->COD;
    $qtd = $item->QUANT_UNID;
    $estoque = $item->ESTOQUE;
    $descricao = $item->DESCRICAO;

    $j = count($cod);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
        echo $cod[$i], ' ';
        echo $descricao[$i], ' ';
        echo $qtd[$i], ' ';
        echo $estoque[$i], '<br>';
    }
}
```

Se for uma tabela em HTML:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>', $cod[$i], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $descricao[$i], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $qtd[$i], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $estoque[$i], '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

No caso usei o `foreach` porque suponho que results possa receber multiplos dados, como:

```
"result":[  
  {  
     "COD": ...,
     "DESCRICAO": ...,
     "ESTOQUE": ...,
     "QUANT_UNID": ...
  },
  {  
     "COD": ...,
     "DESCRICAO": ...,
     "ESTOQUE": ...,
     "QUANT_UNID": ...
  },
  {  
     "COD": ...,
     "DESCRICAO": ...,
     "ESTOQUE": ...,
     "QUANT_UNID": ...
  },
]
```

Comment: Ok vlw, já corrigi o json tbm. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você transforma o json em um objeto e pode usar o `for` para ler cada objeto. 
Algo mais ou menos assim (assumindo que tudo, *COD, DESCRICAO, ESTOQUE e QUANT_UNID* tenham o mesmo número de elementos):

```
$valores = "";
$obj = json_decode($dadosJson, TRUE);
for($i=0; $i<count($obj['COD']); $i++) {
    $valores .= $obj['COD'][$i] . " " .$obj['DESCRICAO'][$i] . " " . $obj['ESTOQUE '][$i] . " " . $obj['QUANT_UNID'][$i] . "\n";
}
echo $valores;
```

Comment: Amigo desculpe, mas preciso lhe informar, esta errado, falta o `results`.

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento, realmente faltou, por isso escrevi que seria *algo mais ou menos assim*, a ideia era mostra como fazer o loop.

Comment: Uma ferramenta para testar online que vc pode usar é o http://ideone.com